# jQuery callback once everything in the DOM is loaded, and after the first, initial load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

A page loads, some scripts, some css, basic DOM, everything is finished.

A user then does something, and a function loads several elements into the DOM. `video`s, `div`s with background images, `img`s. This takes a while.

They are just `append()`ed HTML code, nothing fancy, and the browser then of course starts all of the requests to the respective resources.

I now want a callback event once all of those basic HTTP GET requests are finished. Something like

```
window.onload = function() { .. }
```

or

```
$(window).load(function() { .. });
```

But neither of those seem to work.

I'm dealing with multiple types of elements, so something basic like

```
$('img').on('load',function() { .. });
```

would not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Loop over all the things that you need to wait for and use a load event on each one individually. When they are all done loading, do your thing.

Comment: Would this work for divs with `background-image`s?

Comment: Nope, you would need to get the background image and preload it separately.

Comment: there is no easy end-all-solve-all solution to this other than avoiding the need to do it to begin with.

Comment: So i would use `(new Image()).src = imageSource`, check if its loaded, and the css background-image reference picks up that the image is already cached?

Comment: Bind the load event first, then give the image it's source. The load event will then always fire, eliminating the need to check if it was cached.